# no receive-job results for gci when -path is a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, get-childitem, powershell-jobs

This returns nothing:

```
$x = "C:\temp"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {get-childItem -path $x} | Wait-Job | Receive-job
```

But providing the path parameter without a variable, like so...

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {get-childItem -path C:\temp} | Wait-Job | Receive-job
```

...returns the contents of that temp folder, durrr.txt in this case. This is on Windows Server 2008R2 SP1 with Powershell $host.version output as follows:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Suspecting Powershell's v3, I tried updating a Windows 7 SP1 desktop from v2 to v3, but no luck recreating the problem. On that upgraded desktop, $host.version output now matches the above.

What's going on?

**EDIT / What was going on?**

The busted job seems equivalent to

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {get-childItem -path $null} | Wait-Job | Receive-job
```

So gci returned results for the background job's current directory, the Documents folder, which happened to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass argument to the scriptblock

```
$x = "C:\temp"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {get-childItem -path $args[0]} -argumentlist $x  | Wait-Job | Receive-job
```

In powershell V3 you can do :

```
$x = "C:\windows"
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {get-childItem -path $using:x} | Wait-Job | Receive-job
```

Comment: Hallelujah, thx. But why the different behavior on Win7 vs 2008R2?

Comment: Your code doesn't work either in powershell v2.0/v3.0 on xp, 7, 2008, 2008 r2. The only way to pass variable in a sciptblock is using argumentlist paramenter. In v3 I think you can use `-path $using:x` and it works.

Comment: The first two lines in my question do return results on Win7.  I'll read up on scriptblock arguments.

Comment: @noam Try ook more accurately and you'll find the result isn't the dir of you c:\temp. In my 7 box returns dir of %env:userprofile\documents ...

Comment: D'oh. I tried down-voting myself, but thankfully that is not allowed.